# OpenSSL ECC gf2m modification to apply PCLMULQDQ instruction

Tags: openssl, intel, elliptic-curve, instruction-set

I'm trying to modify OpenSSL code in order to use the PCLMULQDQ instruction to accelerate gf2m operations, as described in the Intel white paper
[Intel Polynomial Multiplication Instruction and Usage for Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/polynomial-multiplication-instructions-paper.pdf)

The paper suggests modifying the following functions in `crypto/bn/gf2m.c`:

- int BN_GF2m_mod_arr()
- int BN_GF2m_mod_mul_arr()
- int BN_GF2m_mod_sqr_arr()
- int rshift1()

with the code snippets in the Appendix. How should I do it? I read the snippets and had no clue how to modify the OpenSSL code.